# Load all technorati script ads tags asynchronously

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance

**What is the issue?**
I have an issue with slow ads loading on my webpage, the Technorati ad tags I am using is blocking the page rendering until the advertising tags loads one by one,

**Example:** *if I have an ad tag in the middle of the page, I can't see the footer of the page until this ad tag loads completely.*

**What I need ?**
I want a method to make the page loads faster and keep these scripts after the whole page is completely loaded (asynchronous), I tried multiple methods but it didn't work.

> Here's the Ad tag code I have to use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   document.write('<scri' + 'pt type="text/javascript" src="'
   + (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https://uat-secure' : 'http://ad-cdn')
   + '.technoratimedia.com/00/81/95/uat_19581.js?ad_size=300x250"></scri' + 'pt>');
</script>
```

> Here's a link to the page I am using the ad tags on:
>   http://feat.youmobile.org/

Comment: Cant you put the script tag directly instead of "building" it like that ?

Comment: @RemyGrandin no, I have to use this code provided by technorati... it generates an iframe with the advertisers content inside

Comment: It would be functionnally equivalent... have you tried to encapsulate the document.write in a jquery loading $(function(){}); ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem has been solved using a javascript library that lazyload ads asynchronously called "Postscribe"

Example of page using PostScribe + HTMLParser http://www.youmobile.org/about/

> Here a link for its Github https://github.com/krux/postscribe

This is the code I used, Huge performance change:

```
<center><div id="ad1" class="center grey-text">Advertisement</div></center>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    postscribe('#ad1', '<scri' + 'pt type="text/javascript" src="'
   + (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https://uat-secure' : 'http://ad-cdn')
   + '.technoratimedia.com/00/81/95/uat_19581.js?ad_size=300x250"></scri' + 'pt>');
  });
</script>
```

Comment: will approve the answer above in 2 days, I hope it helps you all

Answer (score 0):

Try using `defer` or `async` in the generated `script` tag, depending on your intended behavior:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   document.write('<scri' + 'pt type="text/javascript" defer src="'
   + (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https://uat-secure' : 'http://ad-cdn')
   + '.technoratimedia.com/00/81/95/uat_19581.js?ad_size=300x250"></scri' + 'pt>');
</script>
```

UPDATE:

How about only writing it once the document has loaded?  Like:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
       document.write('<scri' + 'pt type="text/javascript" defer src="'
       + (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https://uat-secure' : 'http://ad-cdn')
       + '.technoratimedia.com/00/81/95/uat_19581.js?ad_size=300x250"></scri' + 'pt>');
}
    </script>
```

You can also use `<body onload="writeTheScript()">`, depending on your intention.

UPDATE 2:

That's because the document.write is overwriting the content.  Try it this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var scriptElement = document.createElement('script');
    scriptElement.setAttribute('src',''
            + (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https://uat-secure' : 'http://ad-cdn')
            + '.technoratimedia.com/00/81/95/uat_19581.js?ad_size=300x250');
    scriptElement.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
    document.body.appendChild(scriptElement);
});
</script>
```

Comment: I said above "I tried multiple methods but it didn't work." sadly this is one of them...

Comment: @JosephRaphael well, so make a list of what you've tried, we can't know

Comment: I tried the new code above and now the page is not loading at all http://feat.youmobile.org/